# How exactly sphaleron transitions erase initial baryon asymmetry, if any?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-anomalies, baryogenesis, leptogenesis

The [sphaleron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphaleron) interactions in the Standard Model (SM) is $(B-L)$ *conserving* and $(B+L)$  *violating*. Each sphaleron transition causes the change in the baryon number $\Delta B$ and the lepton number $\Delta L$ be such that $\Delta(B-L)=0$ but $\Delta(B+L)\neq 0$. These facts can be easily verified from the expressions of baryon and lepton current anomalies.

From this, however, it is not clear to me why is it said that *sphaleron interactions will erase any initial baryon asymmetry*? Such a statement can be found in the introduction of this paper "[Baryogenesis without grand unification by Yanagida and Fukugita"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370269386911263?via%3Dihub). I would like to understand this statement mathematically.

Comment: I have probably misunderstood your question, but if initially you had an asymmetry $B \ne 0$, you can end-up with $B = 0$ provided that $\Delta L=\Delta B$. So no way to track the initial asymmetry, no?

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you would cite the corresponding sentence, argument or explanation of the book. Nevertheless, I will try to answer your question.

I think [this paper by Y. Burnier, M. Laine and M. Shaposhnikov](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0511246) might be of interest to you.

The change in baryon number at time $t$ is proportional to the net baryon number at $t$:

$\dot{B}(t)\sim -B(t)+ \eta(t) \sum_{i=1}^{n_G} L_i(t) \ ,$

where $n_G$ is the number of generations and $L_i$ the number of leptons in the $i$-th generation. So the more baryons (and leptons) you have, the faster the changes in those numbers (there is a similar expression for $\dot{L}(t)$).

Furthermore, the sphaleron washout is very rapid at high temperatures. The rate is $\mathcal{A}\sim e^{-E_{sph}/T}$, where the sphaleron energy $E_{sph}=\frac{8\pi v}{9}=\frac{2M_W}{\alpha_W} f\left(\frac{\lambda}{g^2}\right)$ with $f(0)=1.56$, $\ldots$, $f(\infty)=2.72$. (I found this in some notes of mine where I did not cite the source, which I cannot find right now. However, [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/9411050) has a similar result for a $SU(2)$+Higgs theory.)

Comment: Something like this is stated in page 45 of the Physics Letters B I linked. @Clever